# Error in python website blocker program with the normal modules

Tags: python, datetime, web, module, frameworks

I am getting file not found error in this code
Error :-

Working hours
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/PC/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/venv/dearpygui.py", line 418, in 
with open(hosts_path, "r+") as file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/hosts'

'''

```
""" Website Blocker
----------------------------------
"""
import time
from datetime import datetime as dt
hosts_path = r"/etc/hosts" # r is for raw string
hosts_temp = "hosts"
redirect = "127.0.0.1"
web_sites_list = ["www.facebook.com", "facebook.com"]  #  user can modify the list of the websites they want to block
while True:
    if dt(dt.now().year, dt.now().month, dt.now().day, 9) < dt.now() < dt(dt.now().year, dt.now().month, dt.now().day, 22):
        print("Working hours")
        with open(hosts_path, "r+") as file:
            content = file.read()
            for website in web_sites_list:
                if website in content:
                    pass
                else:
                    file.write(redirect+" "+website+"\n")
    else:
        print("Fun time")
        with open(hosts_path, "r+") as file:
            content = file.readlines()
            file.seek(0)  # reset the pointer to the top of the text file
            for line in content:
                # here comes the tricky line, basically we overwrite the whole file
                if not any(website in line for website in web_sites_list):
                    file.write(line)
                    # do nothing otherwise
            file.truncate() # this line is used to delete th trailing lines( that contain DNS)
    time.sleep(5)
```

'''

Comment: You should never change in such manner an important file. Usually you do a temporary copy, you edit, and you move the files when it is fully correct (in your case, buffering may give a program a corrupt file). But it is much easier: just do two copies, and in `crontab` you copy the correct one at correct times. And `pooling` is always a bad idea (checking every 5 seconds if you are in working hours: you can calculate how much you can sleep

Comment: In any case: your problem: you are in windows, and windows doesn't have `hosts` file in `/etc/hosts`. So Python could not find the file. Check where you have the `host` file, and use such path (but look the format of the file before to modify). Note: some browsers will no more use system `hosts` file.

Comment: thank you so much , I am processing it